# Inline sql remove duplicates from results

Tags: sql, sql-server, inline

I have a table with translations for English(`en`) and French(`fr`). I am trying to fall back to `en` when `fr` data is not available with `ctxt.Locale = 'fr' or ctxt.Locale = 'en'`

But, when I have `fr` data query retrieves both `fr` and `en` data and both data sets are displayed in UI.

My requirement is only to retrieve `fr` when data is there and fall back to `en` when no `fr` data available. What is the best way to do this?

Can I use IIF command?

**EDIT**

This is the full SQL command

```
SELECT
    ctxt.ID,
    ctxt.Locale,
    c.ID
FROM
    Category_Table c
INNER JOIN 
    Category_Table_Text ON c.ID = ctxt.ID
                        AND (ctxt.Locale = 'fr' OR ctxt.Locale = 'en')
WHERE 
    c.CatergoryID = 1
```

Edit 2

[image: ctxt table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select both locales, add an artificial priority (per your rules), and only select one of them (the highest one):

```
select top 1 id, locale
from (
  select 1 as priority, id, locale from category_table
    where CatergoryID = 1 and locale = 'fr'
  union all
  select 2 as priority, id, locale from category_table
    where CatergoryID = 1 and locale = 'en'
) x
order by priority
```

Or... you can write:

```
select top 1 id, locale
from (
  select 
    case when locale = 'fr' then 1 else 2 end as priority, id, locale 
    from category_table
    where CatergoryID = 1 and (locale = 'fr' or locale = 'en')
) x
order by priority
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I feel like this is duplicating the same SQL query. Can I retrieve less number of data using count(*) and compare?

Comment: Not sure if your concern is typing/debugging or performance, but I added another version of the query.

Comment: what happens if no french data available in the table?

Comment: When no french data is available, the subquery returns a single row (for English) instead of two rows (French & English). Then, the outer query returns this one.

Comment: I have 122 rows(fr) in my database and it can be changed. how to differentiate fr and en and retrieve only fr data set

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only 2 then you could double join the context.  And coalesce the empty french context value.

For example

```
SELECT 
c.ID, 
COALESCE(fr.Locale, en.Locale) AS Locale
FROM Category_Table c
LEFT JOIN Category_Table_Text fr ON fr.ID = c.ID AND fr.Locale = 'fr'
LEFT JOIN Category_Table_Text en ON en.ID = c.ID AND en.Locale = 'en'
WHERE c.CategoryID = 1
```

But you can also simplify that by defaulting to 'en'.

```
SELECT 
c.ID, 
COALESCE(ctxt.Locale, 'en') AS Locale
FROM Category_Table c
LEFT JOIN Category_Table_Text ctxt ON ctxt.ID = c.ID AND ctxt.Locale = 'fr'
WHERE c.CategoryID = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=31fed0236210d3c9fffe0c2938efa8a1)*

Comment: if I want to add multiple text tables with falling back to English can I do  
                           `COALESCE(ctxt.Locale, ctxt_en.Locale) AS Locale
COALESCE(cptxt.Locale, cptxt_en.Locale) AS Locale
COALESCE(gtxt.Locale, gtxt_en.Locale) AS Locale`

Comment: @SamL FYI, a COALESCE accepts more than 2 values and will return the first in the list that's not NULL. F.e. `COALESCE(null, null, null, 1, 2)` returns 1

Comment: I found out that if I don't have french data in table query returns an empty set. This won't work for my problem. I am wondering ISNULL will work for me?

Comment: [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) is like a [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql). Except that the former only accepts 2 parameters and the later is a standard SQL function.  So don't see how ISNULL would help more.  Maybe you could include some simplified sample data and expected results in your question.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that `Category_Table.ID` should be joined on `Category_Table_Text.ID` ?  More often one has a foreign key in 1 table that points to the primary key of the other table.  So I would have excepted something like a `JOIN .... ON Category_Table.CategoryTextID = Category_Table_Text.ID`